# how the php hash of binary works

Tags: php, coldfusion, lucee

looking at PHP tutorials and have this

```
hash ( string $algo , string $data , bool $binary = false )
```

i use other language and do hash and get the results, if i do not use hash bool as binary = true, if the hash binary = true, the results does not match. Here is my try for what I am doing
example here

**PHP Version**

```
var_dump(hash('sha256', '1612466079678052nonce=1612466079678052', false));
```

**CF Version**

```
lcase(hash('1612466079678052nonce=1612466079678052', "SHA-256", "UTF-8"));
```

produces this result
**Results of PHP & CF**

```
c0363f560d8df85b1f24d3f88e6f32a78370f55b0501a5b0c6d18d0009de2460
```

now i will be setting the boolean value of hash of PHP to true

**PHP Version:**

```
var_dump(hash('sha256', '1612466079678052nonce=1612466079678052', true));
```

**Results of PHP**

```
�6?V ��[$���o2��p�[���э �$`
```

**Now Coldfusion**

```
dump(toString(binaryDecode(lcase(hash('1612466079678052nonce=1612466079678052', "SHA-256", "UTF-8")),"base64")));
```

**Results of CF**

```
sM���z���[���ww����f��~��[ӝ5k��s�u��4��^ێ�
```

Can anyone spot the issue here what i am doing wrong to get the exact results as like PHP is doing

Comment: Your first example shows that the output of the CF code is hexadecimal, but in your second example you're telling `binaryDecode()` that the input is base64.

Comment: yes, the two codes i shared shows. In the first code i am showing that hash works if the php `hash boolean is false`. I was able to replicate the same hex using cf hash. but as soon as i used php hash boolean true, the output is different and then i trioed with CF which is different and does not match, so the error appears where the php boolean true results does not match my try with coldfusion

Comment: I said in my post that CF try might ber wrong because i tried my best to achive the results, so there is something which is i am missing

Comment: Yes. Like I said you're trying to decode hexadecimal as base64. You should decode it as hexadecimal.

Comment: looks like hex did the job, i got the same data.

Comment: @Sammitch Please post that as an answer so Clark can mark it solved (if it's solved)..

Answer (score 1):

First: You are trying to output raw BINARY values as STRINGS ( printable characters ). If you you want to output raw BINARY data as STRING I suggest to use a proper encoding to do that (in both languages). Just printing/echoing/outputting raw BINARY data will always result with many unmapped characters or unidentified UTF-8 character '�'. Thus the data is not a readable printable character.

Second:
Using the functions in PHP:

```
hash('sha256', '1612466079678052nonce=1612466079678052', false);
```

and in CFML:

```
hash('1612466079678052nonce=1612466079678052', "SHA-256");
```

are the same because both output/echo a STRING representation of the binary HASH as HEX (hexadecimal data):

```
c0363f560d8df85b1f24d3f88e6f32a78370f55b0501a5b0c6d18d0009de2460
```

The raw BINARY format of that same data would be (here that data is a STRING represenstation of 0s and 1s):

```
1100000000110110001111110101011000001101100011011111100001011011000111110010010011010011111110001000111001101111001100101010011110000011011100001111010101011011000001010000000110100101101100001100011011010001100011010000000000001001110111100010010001100000
```

If you set the 'set as binary' flag of the PHP hash function to 'true', you will output the above mentioned binary data plain to the output stream, while in CFML you are trying to "base64" decode the HEX string to obtain the raw binary data. That assumption is wrong. What you need to do is to convert the HASH to binary decode from HEX to binary first with:

```
binaryDecode(hash("1612466079678052nonce=1612466079678052", "SHA-256"),"hex");
```

If you use `cfdump` of Adobe's or Lucee's CFML to output the HASH as binary:

```
<cfscript>
    dump(binaryDecode(hash("1612466079678052nonce=1612466079678052", "SHA-256"),"hex"));
</cfscript>
```

, the engines will try to convert the raw binary data as STRING representation on it's own assumption. In Lucee you will see a base64 representation of the same binary data.

[image]

Because with your PHP var_dump function you are outputting the same raw binary data directly to the output stream, you need just to writeoutput that binary data in CFML with:

```
<cfscript>
writeoutput(binaryDecode(hash("1612466079678052nonce=1612466079678052", "SHA-256"),"hex"));
</cfscript>
```

What will have the same result:

```
�6?V ��[$���o2��p�[���э �$`
```

Comment: Tanks for the details, i did removed base64 and the utput  for php and cf are same , so are you saying that output even i same but it is still wrong in the context